# Solving third degree equation involving trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

$2\sin^3 x=\sin x-\cos^2 x+1$. Solve for $x$.

I was able to turn it into a quadratic equation, and obtain the answers of $90$, $210$, and $330$ degrees. But the equation has six zeroes.

Comment: Use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 = 1$ to remove the cosine from the equation, then you'll only have a 3rd degree polynomial.  The $+1$ will disappear and it should be easy to factor then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to $2\sin^3 x=\sin x+\sin^2 x$.

Noting that $\sin x=0$ provides a solution, you can divide by $\sin x$ to obtain a quadratic.

That should give you the additional solutions, $\sin x=1$ and $\sin x=-0.5$.

In the interval $[0^\circ, 360^\circ)$, $\sin x=0$ and $\sin x=-0.5$ have two solutions, and $\sin x=1$ has  one solution.

Comment: So I was right, then

Comment: @Valkyrie (Sorry, I had made a small mistake; I've now fixed it).

If you're looking for solutions in $[0,360^\circ)$, then there are five solutions: $\{0^\circ,90^\circ,180^\circ,210^\circ,330^\circ\}$. If you also include $360^\circ$ in your interval, then since $360^\circ$ is also a solution (since it satisfies $\sin x=0$) there would be six solutions. So, it would seem you forgot to include the $x$'s for which $\sin x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $3$ possible values of $\sin(x)$, but each may correspond to more than one value of $x$ in the interval $0$ to $360$ degrees.